# Two fields index

Tags: java, android, sqlite, indexing

I've got next query:

```
Cursor cursor = ES09SQLiteHelper.getDatabase()
            .query(CompanyDomain.TABLE_NAME,
                    allColumns,
                    CompanyDomain.ADDRESS + " LIKE ? AND "
                            + CompanyDomain.NAME + " LIKE ?",
                    new String[] { Cities.TATARSTAN + city + "%",
                            "%" + query + "%" }, null, null, null);
```

That means `SELECT * FROM companies WHERE address LIKE city% AND name LIKE %query%;` How can I create an index for that? I did following:

```
database.execSQL("CREATE INDEX company_address_index ON "
                + CompanyDomain.TABLE_NAME + "(" + CompanyDomain.ADDRESS
                + " COLLATE NOCASE)");
```

But my index should contain one more field. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
database.execSQL("CREATE INDEX company_address_index ON "
                + CompanyDomain.TABLE_NAME + "(name, address 
                + " COLLATE NOCASE)");
```

Or in plain SQLite:

> CREATE INDEX [name-of-index] ON [table-name]([column1] , [column2] ,
>   ...)

Comment: What about column order?

Comment: @Tony What about it? This is a very useful piece of documentation: https://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html